# How do I confirm in iptables that IP ranges are blocked?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, 19.10, ufw

On Ubuntu 19, I'm using this script [GitHub - Block countries using iptables + ipset + ipdeny.com](https://github.com/mkorthof/ipset-country).

I've installed it, and for testing I've configured it to get two IP lists, and when I run it from the shell, I get no errors in `/var/log/ipset-country.log`.

When I try to list the ranges of IPs blocked using

`iptables -L INPUT -v -n`

I see

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 59 packets, 2873 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
407K  137M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *   *    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
407K  137M ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
33086 1783K ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
32577 1759K ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *    *    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
32577 1759K ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 LOGIPS     tcp  --  *    *   0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0   match-set ipv4-falkland_islands src
0     0 LOGIPS     tcp  --  *    *   0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0   match-set ipv4-ethiopia src
32577 1759K ufw-track-input  all  --  *    *     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

which appears to not show the IP ranges for the two ipv4 IP sets; instead, I see `0.0.0.0/0`.

How can I determine if these two IP lists are being imported correctly?

How can I list the IP ranges that are currently blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, and if working properly, you should see non-zero packet and byte counts for the country blocking rules. Example:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   ...
   60848  3326067 DROP       all  --  enp4s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set china src
    1265    57566 DROP       all  --  enp4s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set hongkong src
   26865  1085462 DROP       all  --  enp4s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set romania src
  193511  7816920 DROP       all  --  enp4s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set russia src
   33149  1358726 DROP       all  --  enp4s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set ukraine src
```

To list the contents of any set do `sudo ipset list SETNAME`. Example:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~$ sudo ipset list romania | head -15
Name: romania
Type: hash:net
Revision: 6
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 65600
References: 1
Members:
193.104.73.0/24
45.131.104.0/22
89.45.66.0/24
91.240.94.0/24
176.223.66.0/24
185.248.136.0/22
46.175.152.0/22
176.116.32.0/20
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I see the difference in what I was trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

if the rules that are shown are what you want, then your firewall is up.

Open a command-line terminal (select Applications > Accessories > Terminal), or login to remote server using the ssh and then type the following command block an ip address as follows:

```
# /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 65.55.44.100 -j DROP
```

To view blocked IP address, enter:

```
# iptables -L INPUT -v -n
```

OR

```
# iptables -L INPUT -v -n | less
```

Task: Check Banned IP’s Linux
Use the grep command as follows to verify that an IP address 1.2.3.4 is blocked or not:

```
# iptables -L INPUT -v -n | grep "1.2.3.4"
```

How Do I Delete or Unblock IP Address 1.2.3.4?
Use the following syntax to delete or unblock an IP address under Linux, enter:

```
# iptables -D INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

Finally, make sure you save the firewall:

```
# service iptables save
```